# $G$ be an abelian group . . . show that $G$ is cyclic

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be an abelian group of order $nm$ where $\gcd(n, m) = 1$. If $G$ contains elements $a$ and $b$ of order n and m respectively, then show that $G$ is cyclic.

I highly appreciate some guidance/clue to start solving.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Show that the subgroup generated by $ab$ contains the subgroup generated by $a$ and the subgroup generated by $b$ and hence has order at least $\operatorname{lcm}(n,m)=nm$, hence is the full group.

To do so you might first want to recall that elements $g^l$ and $g$ generate the same group when $\gcd(l , \operatorname{ord} g)=1$.

Then, consider $(ab)^m = a^mb^m = a^m$ where we used that the group is abelian and the order of $b$ is $m$. Thus $a^m$ is in the subgroup generated by $ab$. And as $\gcd(m, \operatorname{ord} (a))= 1$ we have that $a$ is in the subgroup generated by $a^m$.

Do the analogue thing for $n$ and $b$.

Alternatively you could argue that $a^m$ has order $n$ and $b^n$ has order $m$,  to conclude that $\langle ab \rangle$ that contains both has order at least $\operatorname{lcm} (n,m)= nm$.

Comment: How $\langle a \rangle$ is a subgroup of $\langle a+b \rangle$?! $a\in \langle a \rangle$, but $a\in \langle a+b \rangle$ only if $b=0$. Also, I don't know what does "co-prime" means. And, why $(a+b)^n=e$?

Comment: Co-prime is short for the gcd is $1$. Since it seems you use multiplicative instead of additive notation it is best I update the answer.

Comment: I expanded the answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot. BTW, I couldn't understand the last paragraph. If $a$ and $b$ are elements of $G$, so are $a^jb^k$. If $|a|=n$ and $|b|=m$ then order of $G$ is at least $nm$ (product of number of possibilities for $j$ and $k$) not $\text{lcm} (n,m)$, even if $\text{gcd} (n,m)>1$ ?

Comment: You are welcome. It is true that all these elements are in the group but note they are perhaps not distinct. For an extreme example, suppose $a=b$. But there would be others too.